# Parse JSON to cofigure android application

Tags: java, android, json, performance, android-intent

In my android app, I have to use JSON from server to make specific adjustment in the app.
I'm trying to achive is to read this json and store all the values into local variables to perform actions inside the app.

JSON From server:

```
[

    {
        "sett": " ",
        "glHdr": {
            "sm": [ ],
            "scleHPad": false,
            "st": "sbsm"
        },
        "colrBG": [
            23,
            105,
            184,
            100
        ],
        "colrTB": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "colrTR": [
            255,
            255,
            255,
            100
        ],
        "glFtr": {
            "icoSz": "icoSzN",
            "sm": [ ],
            "scleHPad": false,
            "gvNR": 3,
            "gvHIT": false,
            "gvNC": 3,
            "st": "igsm"
        },
        "statBr": true
    },
    {
        "sm": [
            {
                "tbico": "b43-jeep.png",
                "t": "Welcome!",
                "w": "http://google.com/start",
                "st": "w",
                "wTBL": "wTBLN"
            },
            {
                "t": "Content screen title",
                "f": "Eltec%20Spec%20sheet%20Gim%20RD30W.pdf",
                "st": "f"
            },
            {
                "tbico": "109-chicken.png",
                "t": "Sub menu",
                "sm": [
                    {
                        "t": "Screen 1",
                        "st": "f"
                    },
                    {
                        "t": "Screen 2",
                        "w": "Http://google.com",
                        "st": "w",
                        "wTBL": "wTBLT"
                    }
                ],
                "st": "sm"
            },
            {
                "st": "f"
            }
        ],
        "st": "tbm"
    }

]
```

To parse This I have created Parse JSON class, and trying to come up with method to read and store value of this json in my app.

Function to do this:

```
public void doScanAppConfigJson(){

private static final String = TAG_TITLE;
private static final String = TAG_WEB_ADDRESS;
private static final String = TAG_SCREEN_TYPE;
private static final String = TAG_FILENAME;


        JSONArray appConfig = null;

        // Function for looping json object via ParseJson class.
        //Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        //Getting json strings from url
        JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try{
        //Getting array of settings
        appConfig = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfigConstants.TABLE_VIEW_SUB_MENU_CONFIG);
        //loop throw all the objects under -sm[]
        for (int i = 0; i < appConfig.length(); i++){

            JSONObject sm = appConfig.getJSONObject(i);

            //Now store each of this json in local constant var.

            String tabTitle = sm.getString(TAG_TITLE);

            String webAddress = sm.getString(TAG_WEB_ADDRESS);

            String screenType = sm.getString(TAG_SCREEN_TYPE);

            String fileName = sm.getString(TAG_FILENAME);

        }

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }
```

getJSONFromUrl Method:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        //Global authentication for link username and password.
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){

            return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());   
            }

        });

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

And Im getting errors: `settingsjava.lang.NullPointException` on this but i have define vars, Please some one tell me how do i parse above JSON. Am i on a right track to achieve ans. of my question?

Comment: You have to post the error or we can't help you.

Comment: http://codeworkx.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/jacoj.jpg

Comment: plz look at updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current json string format is :

```
[  //<<<< JSONArray

    {   //<<<< JSONObject
       // other items here...
    }

]
```

this Json string content `JSONArray` as root element instead of `JSONObject`. you will need to convert it first JSONArray then extract JSONObject from it :

```
JSONArray jsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

also change `getJSONFromUrl` method return type to `JSONArray`

Comment: Thank you:), so you saying convert the json to JSONArray? any idea how?

Comment: @Dixit : yes i have lots of ideas just post getJSONFromUrl method code with question then i will edit it

Comment: @Dixit : u have something like `JSONJSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);` in getJSONFromUrl method ? then change it to `JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(response);`

Comment: I have just added `getJSONFromUrl` method here :)

Comment: I don't think i have that response in `getJsonFromUrl` method, I have posted that method here, can you find any fix to it?

Comment: @Dixit : this is an idea how u parse current json to get values from it not copy-paste code. i think u will need to change it according to ur need

Comment: THANKS YOU MATE, I got it now. hit me on google plus:  https://plus.google.com/103405375045630693169

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K: I dont know, but i'm still getting error:  http://cl.ly/image/0z1u2v30341G

Comment: @Dixit : means json String is not valid. because u are getting HTML also in response from server. u have two option either change ur server side code or use String methods to extract only json part from current string

Comment: issues been solved, I used your method which worked fine, Thanks you. Now i was thinking to move to gson since its less messy; Do you have any thoughts on gson compare to json lib in android?